adding plugins while using flutter_eval for SDUI in flutter
I have been trying to use fl_charts while using flutter_eval to achieve SDUI code. The code is attached below.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_eval/flutter_eval.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const EvalExample());
}

class EvalExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const EvalExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const EvalWidget(
      packages: {
        'example': {
          'main.dart': '''
              import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
              import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';

              class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
                const MyApp({super.key});

                // This widget is the root of your application.
                @override
                Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                  return MaterialApp(
                    title: 'flutter_eval demo',
                    home: const MyHomePage(title: 'flutter_eval demo home page'),
                  );
                }
              }

              class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
                const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

                final String title;

                @override
                State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
              }

              class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
                _MyHomePageState();
                int _counter = 0;

                void _incrementCounter() {
                  setState(() {
                    _counter++;
                  });
                }

                @override
                Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                  return Scaffold(
                    appBar: AppBar(
                      title: Text(widget.title),
                    ),
                    body: Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          const Text(
                            'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                          ),
                          AspectRatio(
                            aspectRatio: 2.0,
                            child: LineChart(LineChartData(lineBarsData: [
                              LineChartBarData(spots: const [
                                FlSpot(0, 0),
                                FlSpot(1, 1),
                                FlSpot(2, 4),
                                FlSpot(3, 9),
                                FlSpot(4, 16),
                              ])
                            ])),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            '\$_counter',
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ),
                    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                      tooltip: 'Increment',
                      child: Icon(Icons.add),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              }

            '''
        }
      },

      /// In debug mode, flutter_eval will continually re-generate a compiled
      /// EVC bytecode file for the given program, and save it to the specified
      /// assetPath. During runtime, it will instead load the compiled EVC file.
      /// To ensure this works, you must add the file path to the assets section of
      /// your pubspec.yaml file.
      assetPath: 'assets/program.evc',

      /// Specify which library (i.e. which file) to use as an entrypoint.
      library: 'package:example/main.dart',

      /// Specify which function to call as the entrypoint.
      /// To use a constructor, use "ClassName.constructorName" syntax. In
      /// this case we are calling a default constructor so the constructor
      /// name is blank.
      function: 'MyApp.',

      /// Specify the arguments to pass to the entrypoint. Generally these
      /// should be dart_eval [$Value] objects, but when invoking a static or
      /// top-level function or constructor, [int]s, [double]s, and [bool]s
      /// should be passed directly.
      args: [null],
    );
  }
}

I am getting "Cannot find import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart' (while parsing 'package:example/main.dart') at unknown" error while running the app.
I was expecting to render the fl_charts widget dyanmically

flutter_eval doesn’t know how to access your native Flutter dependencies. To add support for fl_charts you’ll have to create (or find) a bridge and add it as a plugin to flutter_eval’s runtime.
Flutter built-in widgets are supported because the bridging was done for you by the package author. Here’s a list of classes supported out-of-the-box.
